# Custom derived std::exception class's 'what' function returns cryptic nonsense

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, exception, std

I have a custom exception class that derives from `std::exception`:

`CameraControlException.h`:

```
#ifndef CAMERACONTROLEXCEPTION_H
#define CAMERACONTROLEXCEPTION_H

#include <QString>
#include <exception>
#include "ProxOnyx/ProxOnyxUsb1_3M.h"

class CameraControlException : public std::exception
{
    public:
        explicit CameraControlException(QString statusText, int errorNumber);
        virtual const char *what() const noexcept;

    private:
        QString errorMessage;
        int errorNumber;
};

#endif // CAMERACONTROLEXCEPTION_H
```

`CameraControlException.cpp`:

```
#include "CameraControlException.h"
#include <iostream>

CameraControlException::CameraControlException(QString statusText, int errorNumber) :
    errorMessage(QString("Status: ").append(statusText)),
    errorNumber(errorNumber)
{
    this->errorMessage.append("\nSome text in new line");
}

const char *CameraControlException::what() const noexcept {
    // Output the message like return them:
        std::cout << "this->errorMessage.toLatin1().data(): " << std::endl;
        std::cout << this->errorMessage.toLatin1().data() << std::endl; 
            // Works well but function is called twice?!
            // Output:
                // Status: this is an exception test
                // some text 

    return this->errorMessage.toLatin1().data(); // Return the message as 'const char *'
}
```

I have a `QMainView` named `RaGaCCMainView` which handles exceptions in a custom exception handler function. This function catches any `std::exception` and calls `what` to retrieve the error message. Now when actually doing that i just get cryptic nonsense. Here is the exception handler function:

```
template <typename TaskFunction, typename ExceptionFunction>
void RaGaCCMainView::functionCallerExceptionHandler(
    TaskFunction &&taskFunction,
    ExceptionFunction &&exceptionFunction
)
{
    try {
        taskFunction();
    } catch (std::exception& exception) {       // Here i catch any exception
        std::cout << "exception.what(): " << std::endl;
        std::cout << exception.what() << std::endl;
            // Calling what here just gives some cryptic nonsense:
            //      ÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝ
            // NOTE: I get the output inside the 'what' function twice!

        exceptionFunction();
    }
}
```

I use this exception handler by calling it in any other function passing a lambda which holds the functions specific logic. For this problem i used the *on_clicked* function of a `QPushButton` named `someButton`:

```
void RaGaCCMainView::on_testButton_clicked()
{
    this->functionCallerExceptionHandler([]{
        throw CameraControlException(QString("this is an exception test"), 1);
    }, []{});
}
```

Actually I have no idea where the problem lies. I just retrieve a reference to an existing exception calling it's existing what function which obviosly get's called once, but for whatever reason executed twice.

I just want to retrieve the error message stored in `CameraControlException`s `errorMessage` returned properly when calling the `what` function...

Can someone enlight me on where the problem lies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QString::toLatin1` returns a temporary `QByteArray`.  This gets destroyed before `CameraControlException::what` returns, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

Simplest fix would be to store the result of `QString::toLatin1` as a class member variable so it outlives the call to `CameraControlException::what`.

Comment: `std::exception` has an internal `std::string` to back its `what()` method. The simpler solution is to just pass the result of `toLatin()` to the base `std::exception` constructor and not override `what()` at all.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers described the problem. Since you really care about `what`, and not a `QString`, just store a `QByteArray` (or equivalent) instead of a `QString`. `QByteArray` and `std::string` have similar interface and thus the code can be trivially adapted to use either one.

Other notes: When taking inputs that are not arithmetic nor pointer types, pass them by const reference. The data members are immutable and should be declared const. It's such a small class that keeping it header-only makes much sense. It's unnecessarily hard to follow such code when there's so little spread across multiple files. Especially - don't post such code verbatim in the question. Minimize it first.

I also demonstrate how to deal with adding error number into the message.

```
class CameraControlException : public std::exception {
    public:
        explicit CameraControlException(const QString &status, int errNo) :
           CameraControlException(status.toUtf8(), errNo) {}
        explicit CameraControlException(const QByteArray &status, int errNo) :
           errorMessage(makeMessage(status.data(), errNo)),
           errorNumber(errNo) {}
        explicit CameraControlException(const std::string &status, int errNo) :
           errorMessage(makeMessage(status.data(), errNo)),
           errorNumber(errNo) {}
        explicit CameraControlException(const char *status, int errNo) :
           errorMessage(makeMessage(status, errNo)),
           errorNumber(errNo) {}
        virtual const char *what() const noexcept override {
           return errorMessage.data();
        }

    private:
        using MsgType = std::conditional_t<false, std::string, QByteArray>;
        MsgType const errorMessage;
        int const errorNumber;
        static MsgType makeMessage(const char *status, int errNo) {
           MsgType message;
           message.reserve(128); // typical message size
           message.append("Status (#");
           message.append(QByteArray::number(errNo).constData());
           message.append("): ");
           message.append(status);
           message.append("\nSome text in new line");
           return message;
        }             
};
```

You could also implement `makeMessage` using `snprintf` in a safe fashion:

```
status MsgType makeMessage(const char *status, int errNo) {
  MsgType message;
  static const char fmt[] = "Status (#%d): %s\nSome text in new line";
  auto n = snprintf(nullptr, 0, fmt, errNo, status);
  assert(n >= 0);
  message.resize(n);
  n = snprintf(message.data(), message.size(), fmt, errNo, status);
  assert(n == message.size());
  return message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i might implement this :)